# Angular JS Code Running Before It Is Supposed To Sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, rendering

I am having an issue with my code and can't come up with why this is happening or a solution to solve it. My issue is the updateProduct() function call at the end of the code is being called BEFORE the forEach statement even begins one 1 out of 10 page loads. I can't understand why it is doing this. Does anyone know what would cause this and what would be a solution to prevent this from ever occurring?

I have tried using a promise and that was successful about 7 / 10 page loads. So far, this is successful about 9 / 10 page loads. Really confused how it is completing a loop before it even runs.

```
$http.get('file.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.product_map = {};
        var itemsProcessed = 0;
        $scope.products.forEach(function(item) {
            $scope.product_map[item.sku] = item;
            itemsProcessed++;
            if(itemsProcessed === $scope.products.length) {                    
                $scope.seriesId = $scope.series_map[$scope.hashTag].seriesID;
                updateProduct($scope.series_map[$scope.hashTag].products[0].sku, $scope.series_map[$scope.hashTag].products[0].image);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Either way works. When using the angular.forEach it seems to break about 50% of the time, when I use the javascript forEach it seems to only break about 10% of the time. Seems that the angular way of doing things breaks more often than that non-angular way. I'm wondering if there is some sort of caching bug going on with it.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

Someone posted a comment and then deleted that comment. First of all, thank you for your comment as it was helpful in solving my dilemma. I have 2 http.get functions and I need for each of the functions to complete before the for-loop ends. What was happening is that my first http.get was getting hung up and causing an error. I didn't even think about the first one finishing before loading the second one.

I resolved this with the following:

```
$http.get('file1.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.series= data;
    $scope.series_map = {};    
 }).then(function successCallback(){
    $http.get('file2.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.products_map = {};
        $scope.products.forEach(function(item) {
            $scope.product_map[item.sku] = item;
            itemsProcessed++;
            if(itemsProcessed === $scope.products.length) {                    
                $scope.seriesId = $scope.series_map[$scope.hashTag].seriesID;
                updateProduct($scope.series_map[$scope.hashTag].products[0].sku, $scope.series_map[$scope.hashTag].products[0].image);
            }
        });
 });
```